# Как поставить на страницу гаджет?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! У меня задача относительно javascript. Не могли бы вы помочь с решением?

> Поставить на страницу интерактивные часы из своих имеющихся гаджетов на компе...

Comment: что такое гаджет имеющийся на компе???

Comment: это часы которые в виде гаджета отображаются на рабочем столе

Answer (score 1):

Гаджет для WindowsSidebar - это конечно web приложение, состоящее из HTML и JavaScript.
Но от страниц, запущенных в браузере оно сильно отличается в том смысле, что гаджет может получить прямой доступ к ресурсам компьютера (файлы, запуск программ, системное время и т.д.), а вот страничка в браузере такого не получит ни за что.

Можно конечно адаптировать частично, забрать стили, картинки, скрипты некоторые. Но работать оно будет совсем иначе. Во-первых, чаще всего гаджеты содержат функции WMI, которые недоступны обычной странице. Во-вторых, гаджеты содержат стили, оптимизированные только для IE. В-третьих, всю интерактивность придется реализовывать самостоятельно. Просто каждый гаджет по-умолчанию может то, что внутри браузера реализуется обычно программистами. Например, окно настройки гаджета.